# pandas map string column with a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am not very knowledgeable in pandas

So I have a problem which is the following :

I want to get the number of days based on string column

```
Period
3 days
5 weeks
1 year
```

I want to convert this column into an integer which is the number of days like this:

```
Days
3 
35 
365
```

I have done as follow:

```
def toDays(dt):
    if 'year' in dt:
        for s in dt:
            if s.isdigit():
                return int(s)*360  
    elif 'month' in dt:
        for s in dt:
            if s.isdigit():
                return int(s)*30
    elif 'week' in dt:
        for s in dt:
            if s.isdigit():
                return int(s)*7 
    if 'day' in dt:
        for s in dt:
            if s.isdigit():
                return int(s)   

train_file["Days"]=train_file["Periods"].map(toDays)
```

but that didn't work I would some help in order to map this function into the dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code -

```
import pandas as pd


def convert(s):
    ls = s.split()
    d = {'day': 1, 'week': 7, 'month': 30, 'year': 360}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if ls[1].startswith(k):
            return int(ls[0]) * v

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['3 days', '5 weeks', '1 year']})

df['Col'] = df['Col'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

Output -

```
   Col
0    3
1   35
2  360
```

Comment: Isn't a way to map the Serie instead of creating a DataFrame?